# Sourcing a R file that contains cppFunction function

Tags: r, rcpp

Sourcing a file containing `cppFunction` function does not compile/load the function. Below is the code with two functions one wrapped as string in a `R` function.

```
cat('
rcpp_iter <- function() 
{ 
  Rcpp::cppFunction(\'NumericVector func0_with_RString(NumericVector  df1,NumericVector  df2){ 
int N1 = df1.size(); 
NumericVector df3(N1); 
df3[0]=df2[0]; 

for(int i=1;i<N1;++i) 
{df3[i]=df2[i-1]+df1[i];} 

return df3; 
} 
\') 
} 


  Rcpp::cppFunction(\'NumericVector func0(NumericVector  df1,NumericVector  df2){ 
int N1 = df1.size(); 
NumericVector df3(N1); 
df3[0]=df2[0]; 

for(int i=1;i<N1;++i) 
{df3[i]=df2[i-1]+df1[i];} 

return df3; 
} 
\') 

',file='testcpp.r')
source('testcpp.r')

set.seed(100);x=sample(1:100,10)
flag0 <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0)
```

`rcpp_iter();func0_with_RString(flag0,x)` does not work

`func0(flag0,x)` works

Why doesn't  `func0_with_RString` work after invoking `rcpp_iter`?

Comment: Why do you insist on `source()` when our documentation showed for years how to do it with the inline package, or more recently with Rcpp Attributes and its `sourceCpp()`?

Comment: Sorry @DirkEddelbuettel, I am new to `Rcpp` and your comment made sense to me. I went ahead and used `sourceCpp`. And it works. So,  should  I assume that `Rcpp` was not meant to be used this way?

Comment: You may find the documentation we wrote helpful. For this, look at 'Rcpp Attributes' which is well written.  Also glance at Rcpp-intro and Rcpp-FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is concordant with the answer to: Why `x` is not found in the example below?

```
f <- function() {
   x <- 10
}

f()
print(x)
## Error: object 'x' not found
```

Look at the `env` arg of `RCpp:cppFunction`. You may e.g. pass `env=globalenv()` to bind `func0_with_RString` in the global environment.
But this is definitely not the right way to define a function (unless you're just curious). Refer to @DirkEddelbuettel's comments on the matter.

Comment: Might be true but OP's whole approach goes against years of Rcpp practice.

Comment: I totally agree. But he asked why and he got the answer. Maybe OP's just curious? :)

Comment: Won't agree with that :)

Comment: Oops. Meant to say I won't _disagree_ with that :)